# Azure Batch pool quota reached

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-batch

when creating a pool for my Batch account I get the following error message:

```
Pool quota for the account has been reached
```

I currently have no other pool created and when checking the quota of the batch account in the portal, the quota for pools is `20`:

[image]

I am surprised, that the quota for `Spot/low-priority vCPUs` is `0`.

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/quick-create-cli) tutorial.

Is there another quota for the pools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the support. The Azure Portal showed me a quota of 20 pools for this batch account, but internally the quota was 0. The increased the pool quota to 5 and I could create pools again. Now, in the Azure Portal the correct quota of 5 pools was displayed. It was some kind of a bug.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment*** and even I don't have any other pool on my account if you are using azure free trial by default, you receive this quota like below:

[image]

***In my environment with this quota, I am able to create jobs successfully like below:***

I have ***created pool*** like below:

[image]

[image]

And ***added job***:

[image]

Select the job to open the **Tasks** page and added task like below:

[image]
[image]

Hence, with this quota itself we can able to create a pool and added task successfully if you want to increase the quota you can utilize the request quota by following this [blog](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/batch/batch-quota-limit.md) by *uglide*

After some business days quota may increase like below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. But I get the error message when I try to create the pool. It states that the pool quota for my account has been reached. I only find the pool quota in the Quotas section of my batch account. Is there another place, where pool quotas are defined?

Comment: Yes, but a quota of 20 pools should be enough if I don't have a single pool yet. But I contacted the support.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but it did not help me solve my issue. There was some kind of bug in the Azure Portal. See my answer for further details.